# Position between child and father

Tags: css, css-position, parent-child

What is default **child** position in CSS when parent position is **relative** ?

for example:

```
     <div class="face">
        <div class="left-eye"></div>
        <div class="right-eye"></div>
        <div class="nose"></div>
    </div>
```

what is left-eye default position ?

Comment: you mean what by *default position*? if you are talking about the property then it's static for everyone

Comment: I think you're trying to figure out some bug in your code which when you toggled the position of the parent seemed to go away or something like that probably a stacking issue if i know my positions well, i suggest you ask the full question because knowing a default value for a property is a simple matter of a 2 seconds google search.

Answer (score 0):

The default position property for all elements will be `static` irrespective of it's parent element or any other element. You'll have to manually write CSS to change the position of any CSS element(s).

So in your example, `left-eye` will have position of `static`, similarly `right-eye` and `nose` will also have `position: static`.